# How to evaluate "(1.25 > 8)? (2.3125 * sin(90) * 1.25) : (2.3125 * sin(90) * 8)" in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am using `org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser` for parsing a `String` expression but when I add `sin(90)` to this expression I am getting the following error:

> EL1011E:(pos 50): Method call: Attempted to call method sin(java.lang.Integer) on null context object error.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think you want to use `Math.sin()` but I can't be certain.  Can you show us the full code you are dealing with?

Comment: Yes i tired with Math.sin() then  i was getting this error EL1007E:(pos 55): Field or property 'Math' cannot be found on null.

Comment: public static BigDecimal eval(String formula){
  
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
  return parser.parseExpression(formula).getValue(BigDecimal.class);
  
  }

Comment: Does this string always have the condition of `(1.25 > 8)`? While this doesn't directly solve your problem, wouldn't only sending `2.3125 * sin(90) * 8` be better? Did you try importing the library `java.lang.Math`?

Comment: my actual formula is (A > C)? (B * sin(y) * A) : (B * sin(y) * C) .yes i tired java.lang.Math i am getting same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) manual.

Option 1: [§9.5.12 Functions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions):

> You can extend SpEL by registering user defined functions that can be called within the expression string.

Option 2: [§9.5.9 Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types):

> The special `T` operator can be used to specify an instance of java.lang.Class (the *type*). Static methods are invoked using this operator as well.

If you go with option 1, you can register the `sin()` function, and the expression will work unchanged.

If you go with option 2, then this is how the expression should look:

```
(1.25 > 8) ? (2.3125 * T(Math).sin(90) * 1.25) : (2.3125 * T(Math).sin(90) * 8)
```

Comment: See? Reading the manual actually proves answers. And it's fast and free too.